# Issue shortening dynamic URLs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, asp-classic, helicontech

I've searched and tried several possible solutions.

I begin with:

```
http:// example.com/ 729/start-page.asp?cid=4004  
http:// example.com/ 729/start-page.asp?cid=7916
```

and trying for:

```
http:// example.com/ johns-start-page  
http:// example.com/ judys-start-page
```

or if possible:

```
http:// johns-start-page.example.com/  
http:// judys-start-page.example.com/
```

so far I've got:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cID=4004$  
RewriteRule ^729\.asp$ /johns-start-page [NC,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^cID=7916$  
RewriteRule ^729\.asp$ /judys-start-page [NC,R=301,L]
```

Comment: @Jon Lin, Tried your first solution but it's being ignored. Not sure if {THE_REQUEST} is a place holder or
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} goes into the code verbatim.

Comment: This was my first question on SO. I see now that it was a badly asked or plain crappy question with the -2 vote. I could have used advice on better questions instead of a kick in the ass. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you're hardcoding these things, you can try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+729/start-page.asp\?cid=4004($|\ |\&)
RewriteRule ^ /johns-start-page? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+729/start-page.asp\?cid=7916($|\ |\&)
RewriteRule ^ /judys-start-page? [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^johns-start-page$ /729/start-page.asp?cid=4004 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^judys-start-page$ /729/start-page.asp?cid=7916 [L,QSA]
```

For the subdomains, you're going to need to make sure you have DNS setup to point those subdomains to the same IP address. Then something like:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^johns-start-page\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+729/start-page.asp\?cid=4004($|\ |\&)
RewriteRule ^ http://johns-start-page.example.com/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^judys-start-page\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+729/start-page.asp\?cid=7916($|\ |\&)
RewriteRule ^ http://judys-start-page.example.com/? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^johns-start-page\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /729/start-page.asp?cid=4004 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^judys-start-page\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /729/start-page.asp?cid=7916 [L,QSA]
```

But all your links could break unless you've set them up to include a FQDN.